# Issue while deploying wcf service in load balancer environment

Tags: asp.net, windows, wcf

I configured a load balancer service for port 80 on two windows server 2003 machines. I deploy the same wcf service on IIS and shared the virtual IP to client to consume the service.

If both the servers are up and running then clients able to consume the service but of any server goes down it throws the below exception :-

> There was no endpoint listening at server port that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Any idea ?

Comment: How are you monitoring the services on each machine?

Comment: If the load balancer forwards the request to the server that is down, then this would be the expected outcome I guess. What is your real question?

Comment: Have you configured the load balancer correctly? Have you checked the heartbeat intervals at which the load balancer is checking the servers for uptime? Are you connecting to the virtual DNS / IP address?

Comment: I am connecting to the load balancer through virtual IP. I configured the LB service on two servers and if I stop the IIS any of the server then this issue occurs.

Now the question is why the LB service fwding the request to the server that is down. It shoull be inteligent enough to decide where to fwd the request ?